# Error : required from here

Tags: ros-groovy, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have problem in eclipse program.
I used simplest code for publisher and I get on this problem:
`required from here` by this statement (line 38):

```
  output_modem_publisher_.publish(m2);
```

The code is :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <sstream>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher output_modem_publisher_;
    const std::string modem_topic_ = "monsun/modem/in";
    output_modem_publisher_ = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>(modem_topic_, 1000);


  ros::Rate loop_rate(15);

  int count = 0;

  while (ros::ok())
  {

        std::string out_modem2;
        std::stringstream monsun2;

        monsun2 << 2 << "Ammar" ;
        out_modem2 = monsun2.str();
        std_msgs::String m2;
        m2.data = out_modem2;
        output_modem_publisher_.publish(m2);
        ROS_INFO("m2222222222 ");

    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();

    ++count;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And the output of build project is:

16:12:09 **** Incremental Build of project modem_test-RelWithDebInfo@modem_test ****
/usr/bin/make -j8 all
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
Re-run cmake no build system arguments
[rosbuild] Building package modem_test
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.63
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

```
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
```

-- Build files have been written to: /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build
cd build && /usr/bin/make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' /usr/bin/cmake -H/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test -B/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0 /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all make[2]: Entering directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' cd /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color= make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' make[3]: Nothing to be done for` CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/depend make[3]: Entering directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'
cd /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build make[3]: Entering directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build'. make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' cd /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color= Dependee "/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/src/test.cpp" is newer than depender "CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/src/test.cpp.o". Clearing dependencies in "/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/depend.make". Scanning dependencies of target modem_test make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles 4 [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/src/test.cpp.o /usr/bin/c++    -O2 -g -I/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/include -I/opt/ros/groovy/include    -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME='"modem_test"' -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -o CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/src/test.cpp.o -c /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/src/test.cpp In file included from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:32:0, from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/ros.h:45, from /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/src/test.cpp:9: /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h: In instantiation of ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >]’: /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/src/test.cpp:38:37:   required from here /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress] Linking CXX executable ../bin/modem_test /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1 /usr/bin/c++   -O2 -g     -pthread CMakeFiles/modem_test.dir/src/test.cpp.o  -o ../bin/modem_test -rdynamic -L/opt/ros/groovy/lib -lroscpp -l:/usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so -l:/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so -lrosconsole -l:/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so -l:/usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so -lxmlrpcpp -lroscpp_serialization -lrostime -l:/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so -l:/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so -l:/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so -lpthread -lcpp_common -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/groovy/lib  make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles  4
[100%] Built target modem_test
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build' /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build/CMakeFiles 0 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/amory/ros_workspace/modem_test/build'

In addition I have long time to complete the build project (took 13s.183ms)

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59229/error-:-required-from-here/) by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is probably a bug in Eclipse output parser. If your code compiles and there is no errors on console output of Eclipse then you are fine.

I usually have same 'errors' on `publish()` functions, but it is harmless. It is a bit annoying though that Eclipse highlights these lines as erroneous.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0